# Cassandra JVM Max Heap Size

Tags: cassandra, jvm, max, size, heap-memory

Yes this question has been answered many times and yet I have this problem, I have read many articles and I have configured an monitored and yet I face this issue.
I tried with default Cassandra config and also with changing the Maxheapsize to 1/4( system memory), mine is 16GB RAM, but still When I start Cassandra, it starts with 4GB memory and after 24 hours, it starts eating whole 15GB and then Cassandra crashes and gives No queries tried error.

1. Why the memory is increasing?
2. How to stop it?.

Two very high priority question. I need support.

Comment: You need to share a bit more info here to get the right kind of help. Try looking for any ERROR or WARN messages in the logs prior to the "crash". Do you see an OOM? What does `nodetool tpstats` show in the logs (sometimes this is posted out if there is long GC or certain events like dropped messages). What kind of load is on this cluster? Writes? Reads? Try adding as much info as you can, have alook at this blog also to help you with what to look for. https://academy.datastax.com/support-blog/troubleshooting-datastax-enterprise

Comment: Also these might help - [A Deeper Dive - Diagnosing DSE Performance Issues with Ttop and Multidump](https://academy.datastax.com/support-blog/deeper-dive-diagnosing-dse-performance-issues-ttop-and-multidump) and [Amy's Cassandra 2.1 tuning guide](https://tobert.github.io/pages/als-cassandra-21-tuning-guide.html)

Comment: There are companies which provide commercial support for Cassandra, if they don't know, no one does.  My guess is that its using ~11 GB of off-heap memory before the machine runs out.  I would try it on a larger machine or with a smaller data set.

Comment: Update your question with GC info and workload numbers. You can run C* on a 16GB box.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments, But i guess I need to start from scratch to sort this out, I need to fix this, so Ill listen to u all

Comment: Yes, Im pushing data which goes to cassandra, Pushing just three parameter in 30 seconds. I have used default config. Tell me what info do you want? Ill share, When my cassandra started it was 4GB memory consumption, BUt now after 15 hours, its 9 Gb, What to do? My system has 16GB RAm. So it occupies 4GB for JVM rgt? I have read cassandra uses 4GM RAM minimum, so is that 4GB= JVMs 4GB.

Comment: But everytime i restart cassandra, It again starts from 4gb memory, and increases again. But what is this all about? So confusing.

Comment: at first, you should to check syslog of the kernel and check why Cassandra crashed.Double check that you set some things like that in your jvm options "-Xms3500M -Xmx3500M"

Comment: Yes I have set that. I believe by default it takes 1/4 of system memory, which for me is 4GB ( cuz my system memory is 16GB), it starts with 4GB, and now after a day it reached 11GB. So does it ever end piling up the memory,? Doesn't it automatically stop or clear? Ssly what shud I do.

Comment: Something interesting happened,. After day, the memory consumption was 11.5GB. then after two hours, it came back being 8GB memory consumption. What was that? So it reached the threshold and dumped and came back? But what's the calc here, Mm y default Xmx xms is 4GB, and Xmn is 400Mb as per my system config.